# QT Button Press On Widget

Tags: c++, qt

pretty new to using Qt. I have a custom widget that i need to have recieving button presses, then from that button press finding the position of the mouse on the widget. 
Unfortunately, currently the mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *me) doesn't seem to be working correctly. 
So i'm wondering what exactly i'm doing wrong, code below;

Header File:

```
#ifndef TILESHEETPANE_H
#define TILESHEETPANE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "global.h"

class tileSheetPane : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT

 public:
     tileSheetPane(int scnWidth, Global *global, QWidget *parent);

 protected:
     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *me);
     void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

 private:
     Global *tempGlobal;
     QPoint cursorPos;
     int tileSheetPaneWidth, tileSheetPaneHeight, renderOffsetY;
 };

 #endif // TILESHEETPANE_H
```

Src File:

```
   #include <QPainter>
   #include <QMouseEvent>
   #include "tilesheetpane.h"

   //Constructor & Paint Event .. 

   void tileSheetPane::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *me)
   {
        cursorPos = me->pos();
   }
```

CursorPos's values just say at their initialized 0. So any help would be greatly appreciated :), as i said, pretty new to using QT only started probably 2 days ago so i'm still trying to figure out things :D.

Edit;
So after trying out some of the suggestions in the comments, nothing seems to be working. I do indeed have setMouseTracking(true) but still nothing. I inserted a qDebug call into the function as suggested and it seems that the mousePressEvent never gets called.

```
 void tileSheetPane::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *me)
 {
     cursorPos = me->pos();

     //These Never Show Up!
     qDebug() << me->pos().x();
     qDebug() << me->pos().y();
 }
```

Something perhaps is blocking or stopping this being called but im not sure what it could be?

Comment: What you are doing looks correct, so can you show how you are determining the value of `cursorPos`?

Comment: Yup, code which u shown is correct.

Comment: Try to put `QWidget::mousePressEvent(me);` just before the `cursorPos = me->pos();` line in your overloaded event. I am not sure why, but in the past, this call solved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @cmannett85 - I am simple printing to the screen the value of cursorPos via painter.drawText;
painter.drawText(50, 50, QString::number(cursorPos.x()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just couldn't get the mouse clicking working, so after doing some searching on google, i eventually found the following video; 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E29KiTRYpjk

As my widget is rather small anyway, i basically just re-did the entire thing. But it was worth it. 
Essentially i deleted my old files, created a Qt Designer Form, added in a new widget into my mainWindow.ui file, promoted it to use "tileSheetPane" and that's it. Works perfectly now :D.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
qDebug() << me->pos()->x();
```

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor of your QWidget-child-class add `setMouseTracking(true);`

Without this your widget wont track the mouse position.

[`MouseTracking` property documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)

Comment: I have that but still the PressEvent never gets captured.

Comment: @bali182 That just determines if the widget receives mouse move events even if no buttons are pressed.